# VBA Macro to count minutes

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering if it would be feasible to do the task I'm about to explain via VBA or not.
Basically what I'm trying to do is, go through "DUMMY2" and once the values are "27", I would like to subtract the beginning and end of the "DATETIME" in that range to get the minute count

For example: 05/16/2018 11:05 - 05/16/2018 10:50 --> to get 15 minutes.
And then continue to go through the list skipping "16" , "9", "4" and doing the until it hits the second batch of "27" and goes through the macro again to calculate the minute count.

Thank you very much!

```
Sub Test()

Cells.Find("DUMMY2").Offset(1, 0).Select
Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""


Do While ActiveCell.Value > 26.8 And ActiveCell.Value < 27.1
First = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2)
'maybe that doesn't make sense, but I'm trying to select the cells adjacent to "27"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Select
Loop
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Loop
End Sub
```

Data:

```
5/16/2018 10:35 -0.03   0
5/16/2018 10:40 -0.04   0
5/16/2018 10:45 -0.04   12
5/16/2018 10:50 -0.32   27
5/16/2018 10:55 -0.27   27
5/16/2018 11:00 -0.23   27
5/16/2018 11:05 -0.21   27
5/16/2018 11:10 -0.14   16
5/16/2018 11:15 -0.01   9
5/16/2018 11:20 -0.02   4
5/16/2018 11:25 -0.32   27
5/16/2018 11:30 -0.31   27
5/16/2018 11:35 -0.30   27
5/16/2018 11:40 -0.29   27
```

[image]

Comment: Yes that's totally doable using VBA

Comment: Please read [*Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1188513)

Comment: Oh okay! sorry about that. Will Delete the question

Comment: @sagittarius_88 You don't have to delete it - rather, edit your question with the attempt you've made to solve the problem (assuming you've made one, surely you've tried something).

Comment: Can you possibly paste the table data as text here so it's easier for others to recreate?

Comment: Unrelated to your specific problem, but you should get in the habit of declaring all variables :)

Comment: @DavidZemens, will do thanks! I just started applying VBA to my work 4 weeks ago or so. I appreciate the advice :)

Comment: Does the number 27 always appear in groups of four, as shown, and 5 minutes apart? Is so, then the duration would always be 15 minutes

Comment: What do you want to show in the duration column, the duration from one row to the next, or the total duration for the consecutive rows?

Comment: @GMalc, not necessarily, the real data is about 20000 rows, so I just posted a little sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something that works.  You can update the hard coded column references to named ranges if you'd like

```
Sub cntDuration()


    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim intFlag As Integer
    Dim firstDate As Date, secondDate As Date
    Dim difTime As Long

    'Find the last non-blank cell in column A(1)
    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    intFlag = 0

    For i = 2 To lRow
        If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i).Value > 26.8 And Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i).Value < 27.1 Then
            If intFlag = 0 Then
                firstDate = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value
                intFlag = 1
            Else
                If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i + 1).Value > 26.8 And Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i + 1).Value < 27.1 Then

                Else
                    secondDate = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value
                    difTime = DateDiff("n", firstDate, secondDate)
                    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & i).Value = difTime
                    intFlag = 0
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Basically the line of code that does what you are wanting is the `difTime = DateDiff("n", firstDate, secondDate)`

Comment: wow you guys are geniuses over here! thank you. 
The code sometimes provides inaccurate minutes, but I can troubleshoot from here. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem at all.  If you send me a sample of the data that is inaccurate I can help you trouble shoot as well.